# Passing structure between Python and C using SWIG

Tags: python, c, binding, struct, swig

I’m trying to pass a structure between C and Python using SWIG. I am completely new to Python and C. I searched for `passing structure using SWIG`, without success.

I based my code on examples from [SWIG Python tutorial](http://swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf), page 55 and 56. It should fetch the input values from Python, multiply them by 2 in C and return the results to Python. I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new_info`.

sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sample.h"

struct info sample;

void getstruct (struct info *sample);

void getstruct (struct info *sample) {

   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int k = 0;
   int l = 0;

   i = 2 * sample->i;
   j = 2 * sample->j;
   k = 2 * sample->k;
   l = 2 * sample->l;

   sample->i = i;
   sample->j = j;
   sample->k = k;
   sample->l = l;

   return(&sample);

}
```

sample.i

```
%module sample
%{
typedef struct
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int k;
   int l;
} info;

extern void getstruct (struct info *sample);

info *new_info(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
    info *in = (info *) malloc(sizeof(info));
    in->i = i;
    in->j = j;
    in->k = k;
    in->l = l;
    return in;
}

void delete_info(info *in) {
    free(in);
}
%}

extern void getstruct (struct info *sample);
typedef struct
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int k;
   int l;
} info;
```

Command executed to build the wrapper:

```
swig -python sample.i
gcc -fPIC -c sample.c sample_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7
ld -shared sample.o sample_wrap.o -o _sample.so
```

Python error:

```
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sample
>>>
>>> print sample
<module 'sample' from 'sample.pyc'>
>>> print sample.getstruct(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getstruct() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
>>> v = new_info(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'new_info' is not defined
>>> v = sample.new_info(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new_info'
>>>
```

Comment: Which part of the code works for you? Did you write it from scratch?

Comment: I write it from scratch. I have referred the link swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf Page no 55, 56. I have updated the question section with updated program. Please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: I edited your question to formulate it as succinctly as possible, remove exaggeration (*searched everywhere*; this harms your credibility) and split the code block to include just one file in each block. Please [edit] to include what you *do understand* and how you tried to debug your issue.

Comment: You C code should not compile at all. You declare the `info` typedef twice (one error) and then use `struct info` instead of `info` (another error). To work with structures, you don’t need typedef.

Comment: Declaring `getstruct` immediately before its definition does nothing useful, only duplicates code.

Comment: `return(&sample);` is a double error. You are returning a pointer to a local variable (parameter actually; will be overwritten almost immediately, getting a probably nonsensical value) from a void function (which should not return anything by definition).

Comment: Probably you should learn some C and use it to write several simple programs first before trying to combine it with another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sample.i` file, you've added the `new_info` and `delete_info` functions to the wrapper code directly by declaring it within `%{` and `%}`, but did not tell SWIG to generate wrappers for those functions.  Either repeat the code again outside the `%{`/`%}`, or use `%inline %{`/`%}`.  The latter adds the code directly to the wrapper as well as tells SWIG to wrap it.